# ASP.NET dll on .jsp page

Tags: asp.net, jsp, dll, class-library

Is it possible to build a .dll created from a class library in ASP.NET and use it's functionality on a .jsp page?  I know how to create the .dll, but I am not very familiar with .jsp pages.

If you could provide an example of the entire .jsp page, that would be great.  Thanks!

Edit: I guess what I'm trying to say is that I made a new project in Visual Studio (a class library) that has one public function (returns a string) and when it is compiled, it creates a .dll. I would like to use that .dll on a .jsp page.

Comment: Is this dll simply a dot net class library that has nothing to do with asp.net? Your

Comment: Your phrasing of "a class library in asp.net" is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java and ASP.NET don't work together in this case.

You could make a ASP.NET webservice and consume that from your jsp site.

Comment: They certainly can work together in this case without resorting to a web service.

Comment: If you want to pay a lot of money for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jnbridge to use the class library from jsp. See www.jnbridge.com.

Answer (score 0):

There is [mainsoft grasshopper](http://dev.mainsoft.com/), which is a .NET runtime for a Java Servlet container.